# internal server error ruby undefined method

Tags: ruby

so when I run ruby server.rb and go to my local host I get this error.

Internal Server Error
undefined method `new' for ["/home", "/admin"]:Array
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.4.1/2017-03-22) at localhost:8080

Heres the code

## server.rb

```
require 'rack'
require_relative 'view'
require_relative 'route'

class App

  PAGES = %w{ /home /admin}

  def call(env)
    response_headers = {}


    request_cookies = Rack::Utils.parse_cookies(env)


    unless request_cookies["session_key"]
      Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!(response_headers, "session_key", Time.now.to_f)
    end



    count = request_cookies["session_count"].to_i
    count += 1

    Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!(response_headers, "session_count", count)


    route_name = Route.new(env).name



    pages = PAGES.new(route_name, visit_count: count)


    [status, response_headers, [pages.render]]
  end
end

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run App.new
```

## route.rb

```
class Route

  ROUTES = {
    "/home" => :home,
    "/admin" => :admin
  }

  def initialize(env)
    if(env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
      @name = ROUTES[env["PATH_INFO"]]
    end
  end

  def name
    @name || "404"
  end
end
```

## view.rb

```
class View
  def initialize(page, data = {})
    @data = data
    @page = page
    file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "./pages/#{page}.html.erb")
    @page = File.read(file)
  end

  def visit_count
    @data[:visit_count]
  end

  def render
    ERB.new(@page).result(binding)
  end
end
```

Is there a routing error somewhere? I'm not quite sure what it means by undefined method new for my array. Could anyone help and clear this issue?
I was following a guide making this and it seems there might've been error in it somewhere.

Comment: `Array` instance doesn't have method `new`, but you try to call it in `PAGES.new(route_name, visit_count: count)`, obviously.

Comment: right I'm fairly new to programming. How would I go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
pages = PAGES.new(route_name, visit_count: count)
```

you should be doing

```
view = View.new(route_name, visit_count: count)
```

and return `[status, response_headers, [view.render]]`